# Task.Factory.StartNew - ожидание и возврат результата

Tags: c#, async-await

Как запустить пачку фоновых потоков и дождаться любой первый с возвратом результата ?

Пробовал так и ещё различным десятком способов после гугла, в том числе и без лямбды.

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    AnalyseInfo analyseInfo = await myAnalyzer.AnalyseAsync();
    _analyseInfos.Add(analyseInfo);
});


Task<AnalyseInfo> task = Task<AnalyseInfo>.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    return await myAnalyzer.AnalyseAsync();
});


Task<Task<AnalyseInfo>> task = Task<Task<AnalyseInfo>>.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    return await myAnalyzer.AnalyseAsync();
});
```

Но не удалось получить желаемого результата.

Ожидать хотел любую завершившившуюся задачу с помощью `Task.WaitAny`

```
// Дождаться завершения любой задачи
int numTask = Task.WaitAny(_tasks.ToArray());
```

Все попытки заканчивались тем, что задача получала статус завершения, до завершения..

Comment: Не стоит использовать `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, вместо этого лучше использовать `Task.Run()`. Что касается `WaitAny` - этот метод возвращает вам индекс выполненной задачи из массива, что вы отдаете, и тут думаю намек поняли, вам надо из массива по индексу забрать задачу, и взять ее результат. Я думаю вам тут больше подойдет `WhenAny`, который сразу отдает вам завершенный таск. [Примеры](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wNQjP2)

Comment: `tasks.Add(myAnalyzer.AnalyseAsync());`

Comment: Не надо делать StartNew или Run для и без того [асинхронных задач](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/). Вы путаете асинхронность и многопоточность. Нет смысла пытаться получить Task из того что и так возвращает Task. А в качестве комбинатора вам нужен `WhenAny`.

Comment: @aepot смысл делать Run для асинхронных задач есть: иногда задача начинается с долгой CPU-bound части и хочется сделать её параллельно

Comment: Да, у меня глупо вышло( пересидел... а можно было просто await убрать, напихать в список и ждать)) Спасибо всем!

Comment: @PavelMayorov это скорее баг реализации самого метода. Но такое встречается даже в BCL, верно, хоть и не считается самими майкрософтами, что это норма. Например File.ReadAll###Async/WriteAll###Async начиная с .NET 6 зафиксили и работы продолжаются. Асинхронная операция не должна долго стартовать синхронно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` создаёт новую задачу оборачивая возвращаемое значение вне зависимости от этого самого значения.

Поэтому, когда вы пишете `Task.Factory.StartNew(async …)`, вы получаете `Task<Task<…>>` - задачу, значение которой тоже задача.

Рассмотрим асинхронный метод подробнее:

```cs
async () {
    // 1
    await Bar();
    // 2
}
```

Если его вызвать, то он вернёт управление после первого нехолостого оператора await, то есть строчка 1 и вызов Bar будут выполнены синхронно, а ожидание Bar и строчка 2 - асинхронно. Когда вы оборачиваете такой метод в задачу - строчка 1 и вызов Bar выполняются во внешней задаче, а ожидание Bar и строчка 2 - во внутренней.

Именно потому у вас и получалось, что задача завершается слишком рано: вы ждали внешнюю задачу.

Как от этого избавиться? Очень просто: используя Unwrap!

```cs
Task<AnalyseInfo> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    return await myAnalyzer.AnalyseAsync();
}).Unwrap();
```

В этом методе нет никакой магии, если бы его не было - его было бы нетрудно написать самостоятельно:

```cs
async Task<T> Unwrap<T>(Task<Task<T>> task) {
    return await await task;
}
```

Второй вариант - можно использовать `Task.Run`, в отличии от StartNew у него есть специальная перегрузка для асинхронных методов, которая вызывает Unwrap внутри:

```cs
Task<AnalyseInfo> t = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    return await myAnalyzer.AnalyseAsync();
});
```

Наконец, третий вариант - вообще не выносить асинхронный метод в отдельный поток, а просто вызвать. Этот вариант не универсален, но обычно работает:

```cs
Task<AnalyseInfo> t = myAnalyzer.AnalyseAsync();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Хоть и ответ уже дан выше, попробую внести свои 5 копеек с таким примером:

```
var longTask = Task.Delay(10000);
var shortTask = Task.Delay(1000);

var tasks = new[] { longTask, shortTask };

var anyTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

Console.WriteLine(anyTask.Status); //RanToCompeltion
Console.WriteLine(shortTask.Status); //RanToCompletion
Console.WriteLine(longTask.Status); //WaitingForActivation

Console.WriteLine(anyTask == shortTask); //True
```

В таком примере не используется TaskFactory для создания, а используется напрямую ваш таск (что также убирает лишний async и создание лишних стейт-машин для этого таска). В вашем примере в вопросе не хватило кейворда `await` перед `Task.WhenAny`, чтобы задача действительно ожидалась.

Comment: Только ведь тогда у автора вопроса вернулась бы не действительно законченная **внутренняя** задача, а первая закончившаяся обёртка над задачей, если я правильно понимаю. Внешний await не поможет дождаться первую внутреннюю законченную задачу, нужен внутренний await.

Comment: @CrazyElf исходя из данных отладчика, у тасков есть Id. В данном примере при запуске я получил id 8 и 9 для лонг и шорт тасков, для задачи ожидания id 10. Как только таск завершился, ссылка anyTask стала ссылаться на таск с id 9. Если это не просто Task, а Task<T>, то автор может получить возвращаемое значение первого выполненного задания через `var result = anyTask.Result;` ну или как в его вопросе - `analyseInfos.Add(anyTask.Result);`. Если что неверно - прошу поправить, дополню ответ. Версия рантайма - 6.0